# Efficient way to find whether a coordinate is a vertex/border coordinate?

Tags: java, algorithm, if-statement, maze

Imagine a Cartesian plane and every Cell object represents a point in the plane (the plane will be the maze). When building my maze, I want to figure out whether a Cell object is a vertex (the four corner points) or just a border point (any cell that is on the edge of the maze, vertex points are also border points).

I need to know so that I can add neighboring cells as neighbors of the particular cell (I am creating a graph structure with nodes). Different borders have different requirements for what cells are neighbors (a top-right vertex for example cannot have a neighbor that is y + 1 or x + 1 as it is outside of the maze, whereas a bottom-left vertex cannot have y - 1 or x - 1).

How I tried to implement this was through a slew of if statements which I feel isn't a really good practice. So I wanted to ask whether there is a better way to know what type of coordinate a point is?

Here is how I did it:

```
private String typeOfBorderCell(Cell cell){
    if (!isBorderCell(cell)){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("cell is not a border cell");
    }
    double x = cell.getCoordinate().getX();
    double y = cell.getCoordinate().getY();

    // Vertices
    if (x == 0 && y == 0){
        return "bottom-left";
    }

    else if (x == 0 && y == height - 1){
        return "top-left";
    }

    else if (x == width - 1 && y == 0){
        return "bottom-right";
    }

    else if (x == width - 1 && y == height - 1){
        return "top-right";
    }

    // Non-Vertices
    else if (x == 0 && (y > 0 && y < height - 1)){
        return "left";
    }

    // and so on for the other three non-vertex borders
}
```

The height/width are the size of the maze, but I had to subtract 1 as the maze coordinates start at origin (0,0) thus a 5x5 maze goes up to a max of 4 for its y and 4 for its x.

Doing this, I would get a total of 8 conditional statements (and the method that uses this method would require a switch statement with 8 cases as well). Is there a more efficient way to do this without a bunch of conditional statements?

Comment: Well if you need 8 different return types, then you are going to need 8 different conditionals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find enums a reasonably elegant alternative to a long set of `if` statements. Here's an example (using Java 8):

```
enum CellType {

    OTHER(1, (x, y) -> true),
    TOP(2, (x, y) -> y == HEIGHT - 1),
    BOTTOM(2, (x, y) -> y == 0),
    LEFT(2, (x, y) -> x == 0),
    RIGHT(2, (x, y) -> x == WIDTH - 1),
    TOP_LEFT(3, TOP, LEFT),
    BOTTOM_RIGHT(3, BOTTOM, RIGHT),
    TOP_RIGHT(3, TOP, RIGHT),
    BOTTOM_LEFT(3, BOTTOM, LEFT);

    private static final int HEIGHT = 5;
    private static final int WIDTH = 5;

    private final int precedence;
    private final BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> test;

    private CellType(int precedence, BiPredicate<Integer, Integer> test) {
        this.precedence = precedence;
        this.test = test;
    }

    private CellType(int precedence, CellType type1, CellType type2) {
        this(precedence, type1.test.and(type2.test));
    }

    public static CellType valueOf(int x, int y) {
        assert x >= 0 && x < WIDTH && y >= 0 && y < WIDTH;
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(ct -> ct.test.test(x, y))
            .max(Comparator.comparingInt(ct -> ct.precedence))
            .orElse(OTHER);
    }
}
```

You can use this with code like `CellType.valueOf(0, 4)` which will return `CellType.TOP_LEFT`.

I prefer this idiom to sets of if statements because it puts the predicates in one place and makes them easy to identify and change.

It also will result in your 'cell type' not being a string which is a good idea if you later want to add logic to it. For example, you can avoid the switch statement you mention in your question by adding the logic to process the cell type to the enum itself. Also, comparing to strings is pretty error prone. You could change the string in one place and end up with hard to detect bugs. If you change an enum you get an immediate syntax error.

Here's a brief explanation of how it works. A `BiPredicate` is a functional interface that takes two ints (x and y) and returns a boolean. Each of the `CellType` members has a predicate that tests whether a given x and y represent a cell of that type. For the edge cell types, a lambda expression is used to provide the condition. For the vertices, the constructor takes two edge cell types and constructs a new predicate by testing if the cell satisfies both edge conditions. For example, `TOP_LEFT` tests if the cell is on both the top and left edges.

The `valueOf` method finds all cell types that satisfy a given cell then returns the one with the highest precedence. The precedence ensures that vertices are returned rather than edges. If no cell types match then it returns `OTHER` (for non-edge non-vertix).

Comment: I would be expecting CellType.valueOf(0, 4) to return CellType.TOP_LEFT because (0, 4) on a coordinate plane (for a 5x5 maze) is essentially the left side instead of right with would indicate a x value of 4, not 0.

Comment: @Naz you're correct - I mixed my x and y values in the predicates. Hopefully you get the idea anyway.

Comment: I really like the design, but I am still not sure what the predicates really mean. I understand that a predicate is a function that gives back a boolean, however, I'm not sure what `TOP((x, y) -> x <= 0` is really doing though. I just can't make any sense of it (or the other predicates) and how x being less than or equal to makes it top. Can you elaborate on how to fix the predicates to get the more accurate result? I tried messing around with it, but I guess I'm not understanding this.

Comment: I'll adjust the code so that it's correct and add some commentary that might help.

Comment: Thank you! The predicates make much more sense now - such an elegant solution to a rather unsightly list of if statements. Learned quite a bit from this solution.

Comment: @Naz You're welcome. One other thing to keep in mind: comparison with doubles is notorious error prone. You should either convert to using integers or consider changing the predicates to inequalities.